# lookahead negative in xml

Tags: regex, xml

I'm working with xml 1.0, actually xsd-schema, so I use regex restrictions, so I have a problem with lookahead negative. As I've read there is no lookahead function in xml 1.0 restrictions.

Preconditions:

1. String starting and ending with no "/";
2. No "//" in the string;
3. String length is 1-16.

So help me to combine regex equivalent to:

```
([-+A-Z\w\s:?().,'](?:[-+A-Z\w\s:?().,']|/(?!/)){1,14}[-+A-Z\w\s:?().,'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: plan b?

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]([\/][a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9])*$
```

and then:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:simpleType name="LimitedString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:length value="16" />
      <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]([\/][a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9])*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I'm affraid that is not correct expression, because the text like this is match but, won't be: 151201//09010008

Comment: work if u correct [\/] to [/] and remove "^" and "$"

Comment: ah sorry about that a quirk of the regex tester I was using

Answer (score 0):

Just add `^` and `$` to your regex to match only the entire input string:

```
^([-+A-Z\w\s:?().,'](?:[-+A-Z\w\s:?().,']|/(?!/)){1,14}[-+A-Z\w\s:?().,'])$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

See a [demo here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Uwy4wM33XELNxxZo).

---

`\w` is equivalent to `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`, so you can simplify your regex by leaving away `A-Z`:

```
^([-+\w\s:?().,'](?:[-+\w\s:?().,']|/(?!/)){1,14}[-+\w\s:?().,'])$
```